# Android M (6.x) UDP Broadcast Error

Tags: android, networking, udp, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need some help with an excruciating problem...

I have an app using DatagramSocket sending broadcast udp messages on my local network, and this work perfectly when I run it on mobiles android L (5.x) or lower.

The project has the follow permissions: **internet, access_network_sate, access_wifi_state, change_wifi_state, change_wifi_multicast_satate, interact_across_users**, and other permissions.

This bolded permissions was used on my app, during traffic of messages.

During the implementation **TimerTasks, AsyncTasks and Threads** was used to create the DatagramSocket properly, depending of the use, because I know this is necessary to send messages on network (it is necessary run network reader|writer out of main thread).

But the app not working properly when mobiles android M (6.x); anyone message is sending, and I don't have any ideia what the cause of this problem.

I'm try search about permissions on Android M, and I can see news on system permissions, but don't see anything about my specific case.

I will be very grateful if somebody can help me.

Comment: Not working properly? Be more specific please. Errors? Exceptions? Different flow of code? Do you ask for permissions now?

Comment: Any solution? I'm in the same problem. with android M, the "receive" stops randomly. It seems that android M is blocking some UDP packets..

Comment: Hi Coelho, Did you fix it? How?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fix this problem but I change all structure of receive and send udp broadcasts using a custom DatagramSocket udp service listener. My code execute more faster then old one, but I don't have any devices android Loolipop(5.x) or Marshmalow(6.x) to test my code. My doubt persist. On devices 4.x or lower execute very well.

Comment: @greenapps The problem is, I not have any devices 5.x or 6.x to test my app :(, on others devices execute perfectly but some clients uses android 5 or higther, thus I don't have any way to catch erros, exceptions and I don't find any new permission on Android 5 or Higher.